# Java not visible when using oracle self extracting installer for ubuntu

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, installation

I want to install the oracle jdk 6 in ubuntu for all users using the self extracting installer at oracles website (jdk-6u37-linux-x64.bin)

This is what i do step by step:

**1-** Download the jdk-6u37-linux-x64.bin

**2-** Create a folder in the unix system resources and move the downloaded file there

> sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/java
>
> sudo mv /home/sfrj/Downloads/jdk-6u37-linux-x64.bin /usr/local/java

**3-** Make the file executable

> sudo chmod 700 jdk-6u37-linux-x64.bin

**4.** Execute the installer

> sudo ./jdk-6u37-linux-x64.bin

**5.** Remove the installer(Don't need it anymore)

> sudo rm jdk-6u37-linux-x64.bin

**6.** Create a symbolic link

> sudo ln -s jdk1.6.0_37 /usr/local/java/latest

**7.** Edit the file /etc/environment

```
JAVA_HOME="/usr/local/java/jdk1.6.0_37"
JRE_HOME="/usr/local/java/jdk1.6.0_37/jre"
PATH="/usr/local/java/jdk1.6.0_37/bin:\/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
```

**8.** Reload the environment file

> source /etc/environment

So far so good, after all that and without closing the terminal I type: ***java -version***
and I see this:

> java version "1.6.0_37" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build
>   1.6.0_37-b06) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.12-b01, mixed mode)

The problem is, when close the terminal, open it again and type the command **java -version** again, I see this:

```
The program 'java' can be found in the following packages:
 * default-jre
 * gcj-4.6-jre-headless
 * gcj-4.7-jre-headless
 * openjdk-7-jre-headless
 * openjdk-6-jre-headless
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>
```

I am confused:

-Why is this?

-Did I install the jdk correctly?

-What is missing?

I want to install it this way, without using apt-get, so please don't answer to me use apt-get install...

Comment: Any particular reason you don't want to use apt-get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> -Why is this?

You are not setting your path in a way which is reloaded automatically.

> -Did I install the jdk correctly?

There is two ways of installing it. For the self unpacking version this is correct.

> -What is missing?

Your environment is not set correctly.

Comment: How can I make it reload automatically? You think i should export it in the `~/.bashrc` ? I am confused, then will it be accessible by all users?

Comment: This is really a "how do I configure my Unix environment" question. The `~/.bashrc` allows you to change your default settings.  There is an `/etc/profile.d/` directory for scriptlets to add configuration for programs. This is where you can add java for all users.  You might want to add your ide, and/or mvn there as well.

Comment: I just created an script and called it `loadjava.sh` Inside it i typed `export JAVA_HOME="/usr/local/java/jdk1.6.0_37"` and `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/java/jdk1.6.0.37/bin` Following your advice i added it into `/etc/profile.d/` now every time i boot it is loaded and 'java -version' works fine. 
Just one more little question, do you think will i need to give all permiions to that script with chmod 777, or is no needed? 
Thanks for the useful answer.

Comment: As you ran the install as root, the permissions should be correct. 777 is a bad idea because it means anyone can change it to give themselves access to the account which runs it.

Comment: Ok I understand. Just one more little doubt.
Regarding to the file `/etc/environment`, do I have to have the JAVA_HOME defined in there or just having this script is enough? That confuses me

Comment: AFAIK the `/etc/profile.d` is the preferred way. I have not used `/etc/environment` before.

Comment: Ok i thought one was using for defining and the other for exporting, but i see, it is enough just enough to have does export commands in the script inside that folder.

Comment: Having it as a scriptlet like that is self contained. It doesn't change any existing file and you can see all the changes which relate to java on your machine.  You can easily copy that one file to another machine to get the same change.

Answer (score 1):

This is my online guide. There are a few differences, and it works for me.

[JDK Installation - Ubuntu](http://pabloabbate.blogspot.com.ar/2012/12/jdk-installation-ubuntu-distribution.html)

Answer (score 0):

Debian style linux distros have the alternative mechanism for this kind of problems. They link /usr/bin/java to /etc/java which in turn is linked to the correct binary.

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /usr/local/java/jdk1.6.0_37/bin/java 1
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/javac javac /usr/local/java/jdk1.6.0_37/bin/javac 1
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/javaws java /usr/local/java/jdk1.6.0_37/bin/javaws" 1
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/jar jar /usr/local/java/jdk1.6.0_37/bin/jar 1
sudo update-alternatives --config java
sudo update-alternatives --config javac
sudo update-alternatives --config jar
sudo update-alternatives --config javaws
```

You may want to repeat this for the other commands like wsimport. Have a look at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Java. There are also other options listed like using a PPA, but if you strictly don't want to use apt-get, this is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

[These scripts](https://github.com/flexiondotorg/oab-java6) will help you install sun's jdk on Ubuntu. Works great.